# How to get Text color in Button to be like App background?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am recently struggling with one thing in Android Studio. I don't know how to set (or if it's even possible) the text in button to have the same color (or no color at all) as the background in the Activity. What I mean:
[I want this white text in black button to be the same color as App background (gradient)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVUen.png)

Button XML:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/startButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:fontFamily="@font/amiko"
                android:text="START"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Button shape XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<solid android:color="#000000"/>

    <corners android:radius="30dp" />


</shape>
```

I've tried to set text color in Button as transparent, but it became black just like the button color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transparent color for your background color of Button. Just fix Button shape XML color to this value:`#00000000`. The first 2 values represent alpha channel and with this additional `00` you are setting your color to transparent.

**Button shape XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>

    <corners android:radius="30dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I want to make text in my button to be transparent, not this shape. If I do what you've read, my whole button except text just disappear.

Answer (score -1):

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <stroke
        android:color="#388e3c"
        android:width="2dp"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"/>
    <solid
        android:color="#ffff"/>
</shape>
```